# Redis performance comparison: using TTL vs allkeys-lru policy

Tags: memory, redis, blocking, ttl, lru

In Redis, using `allkeys-lru` deletes the key no matter if it's an expire-set key or not.

Using `TTL`, setting an expiration for the key, uses memory.

Quoting from [Redis.io](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache):

> It is also worth noting that setting an expire to a key costs memory,
> so using a policy like allkeys-lru is more memory efficient since
> there is no need to set an expire for the key to be evicted under
> memory pressure.

1. Is it really **more efficient** overall to **NOT** put a `TTL` on the key and let `allkeys-lru` policy handle it?
2. Isn't there any **tradeoffs** in this situation? For example, does the `allkeys-lru` **block the write action** until it completes the expiration? That would make me use the TTL if this expiration is going to take long durations.

I would love to discuss about this. Thanks for everybody's input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allkeys-lru is triggered by Redis allocated memory limit. It's a safety feature to avoid crashing Redis entirely.
If you rely on only allkeys-lru to cleanup your data then your Redis will run slower because any operation would have to be applied to a bigger DB. And your Redis DB will always be at max size.

Also it makes it harder to monitor your resources during your business growth.

Using TTL on your values is more a technical decision based on your use case. It gives you more control over which events you don't need anymore.
TTL uses more memory because it has to store the TTL value for each record, makes sense.

For Redis-Streams, you can use the MAXLEN property to not grow your streams too much, specially when you don't need older data. This property is per stream so it will not increase Redis memory that much.
Redis-streams are expired by stream(by key), not by record. So it's not possible to expire old records from Streams based on a TTL/record if you continuously receive new data.

Main conclusion: Use TTL and MAXLEN where possible to cleanup unnecessary data sooner so Redis will not need to do it all at once and you will have more control over your data and resources.

Comment: Also, on Redis-Streams, if you apply a new EXPIRE time every time you receive a new record that means you have to do 2 operations: XADD and EXPIRE. Depending on your input throughput, this might double your Persisting time. (but Redis is extremely fast, so better do some monitoring before deciding on this)

Comment: Thanks for answering! As an optimisation, XADD and EXPIRE could be completed in 1 pipeline, which would reduce the latency.

About LRU being slow: Are you saying that because, LRU policy block the writes until its evicting enough objects for its memory (so your write operations are taking longer), while the EXPIRE command makes it faster because, the TTL evictions happens concurrently, resulting with your write operations taking shorter time (but you're spending an extra memory for TTL) ? I couldn't understand how LRU is slower.

Comment: yes. Same as why C++ is faster when you handle the pointers manually.

Comment: But again, Redis is very fast. But, doing multiple commands involve multiple network calls , that is different from project to project. It's better to monitor if this has an impact on your system.